# AppleScript - Get the Bounds of Every open Window

Tags: macos, applescript

I have been playing all day with getting this down. The goal being to generate an AppleScript which generates yet more AppleScript. I'll explain in more detail.

THE DESIRED END RESULT: After arranging your windows how you like them follow up with launching this script. This will copy to your clipboard the necessary script to automatically launch, position, and resize the application windows to the current configuration. This would be so that I could send the script to other people who could then, upon launching this script, design their own custom layouts which could then be either pasted into Script Editor or possibly made into a service and bound to a hotkey using Automator.

WHAT I'M CURRENTLY TRYING TO OVERCOME: I can't seem to get it to list the bounds for each window. I am currently running this script.

```
  tell application "System Events"
    set openApps to name of every process whose background only is false

    repeat with theItem in openApps
        set checkApp to theItem
        tell application checkApp to get the bounds of the front window
    end repeat
end tell
```

This spits out the following error every time without exception:

```
error "System Events got an error: Can’t get application \"Finder\"." number -1728 from application "Finder"
```

I'm not asking that someone solve the entire problem for me. Though any advice on the matter is always appreciated. The current hurtle is just to get the bounds of each window set to variables for use elsewhere in the script.

Comment: The size and position would be sufficient. Utilizing the Bounds was the only method I was aware of accomplishing this but if you have something else I’m open to suggestions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This answer focusses on the issue stated under **`What I'm Currently Trying To Overcome`**.  I've interpreted **`The Desired End Result`** to be background information that provides context to your immediately-pressing issue (and this is really interesting/useful to provide, so thank you).

#### TL;DR

```
tell application "System Events"
    set _P to a reference to (processes whose background only = false)
    set _W to a reference to windows of _P
    [_P's name, _W's size, _W's position]
end tell
```

This will get you the list of `size` and `position` properties for each `application process`.  Below is a rather verbose deconstruction of where and why your script went wrong; followed by a proposed solution after considering other equally viable solutions before settling on the base code above.  I will try and trim the wordiness of this answer another day when I'm a bit less tired, but for now, I hope the deeper insight helps.

#### The Issues

▸ Starting with the specific error your script is throwing out, it's necessary to point out that, generally speaking, `tell application` blocks don't often nor should rarely need to be nested.  You opened a `tell` block to target *System Events*, which was necessary to get the `process` names; that's the point when you should have either closed the `tell` block, or used a *simple* `tell` command on a single line:

```
tell application "System Events" to set openApps to the name of every process...
```

(no need for `end tell` in this case).

However, as your `tell` block remains opens, the commands that come next are also directed to *System Events*.  The first `application process` that your script evidently finds belongs to *Finder*, and when your script (inside the repeat loop) is instructed to `tell application "Finder"` (by way of the `checkApp` variable), the error is thrown because you've actually told *System Events* to tell *Finder* to do something, and *System Events* has no understanding of how to do interact with an `application` object.

▸ This leads us onto the following line, with which are a couple of problems pertinent to your script (plus a more general noteworthy aside<sup>†</sup> about which I have left a footnote):

```
tell application checkApp to get the bounds of the front window
```

This line will only work for applications that are (Apple)*scriptable*.  Not all applications can be controlled by AppleScript—it's a feature app makers **choose** to implement (or choose not to, as is ever more frequently the case) when developing their software for macOS.

Those that are scriptable *will* (if they follow Apple's guidelines) have defined `window` objects that each contain a `bounds` property.  Those that aren't scriptable won't have either of these.  That's when another error will be thrown.

Another "minor" issue is that not all of the processes which are `background only` necessarily have windows, and thus a `front window`.  *Finder* is never background only, but sometimes has no open windows.  Therefore, even once the error you're getting has been fixed, this is the next error that crops up if there are no open *Finder* windows.

#### A Solution

Although you can't obtain a `bounds` property of a window belonging to a non-scriptable application, *System Events* can retrieve some properties that belong to objects of an `application process`.  This is independent of whether an application to which the process belongs it itself scriptable or not, because *System Events* is the application we are targeting, which **is** scriptable, and happens to have access to similar information pertaining to each process's `window` objects (**NB.** see the footnote below, but the `window` object belonging to a `process` is **not** the same as the `window` object belonging to an `application`, so cannot be used interchangeably, and nor can their properties).

Although there is no `bounds` property for the `window` objects owned by `processes` of *System Events*, there are two other properties, which, together, are equivalent to `bounds`: `position` and `size`.  The `position` gives the `{X, Y}` coordinate of the top-left corner of the window relative to the top-left corner of the screen (which is defined in this context as being the origin at `{0, 0}`); the `size` gives the `{X, Y}` pair of dimensions that represent the window's width and height, respectively.

Thus, given an hypothetical `bounds` property value of `{, , , }` for a specific window, the relationship to `size: {, }` and `position: {, ℎ}` can be expressed thus:

```
{, , , } = {, ,  + ,  + ℎ}
```

The other consideration is getting a list of processes that actually have windows.  There are various ways to go about doing this, each with advantages and disadvantages, which include brevity of code, execution time, and accuracy of the retrieved list of windows.

Your original method of retrieving a process list discriminated by `background only` is one of the fastest and there are only a few situations where false negatives lead to omissions from the list (namely, menubar applications that register as `background only` yet clearly have a `window`; the Instagram app *Flume* is an example).

You can instead discriminate by the `visible` property, which is just as fast, but I feel less apt in situations where an application is hidden and would need to be unhidden before recording its window properties; or, again, some menubar apps that register as `background only`, not `visible`, yet clearly *are* visible_ with a window in the foreground.

The method that is most reliable in retrieving all windows in any circumstance is, sadly, quite slow, but does produce a list a that's easy to work with and doesn't need further processing.

In our current situation, however, I think it's sensible to choose the option that gives speed and will work for most applications, which is your `background only` filter.  As the list produced from this yields some false positives (*Finder*, for example), we need to process the list a bit before it's reliable to utilise.

Here's the code to retrieve a nested list containing **a)** a list of named processes; **b)** a list of window sizes for each of the named processes; and **c)** a list of window positions for each of the named processes:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set _P to a reference to (processes whose background only = false)
    set _W to a reference to windows of _P
    [_P's name, _W's size, _W's position]
end tell
```

If you close your *Finder* windows, you'll see it still appears in the first list by name, but the second and third lists have an empty list `{}` where its windows' sizes and positions would otherwise be.  So just be sure to do some checking before you try and reference the items of each sublist.

Compare and contrast it with this slower, but more accurate solution:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set _P to a reference to (processes whose class of window 1 is window)
    set _W to a reference to windows of _P
    [_P's name, _W's size, _W's position]
end tell
```

It takes twenty times as long to run on my system, yielding an albeit solution that can identify menu bar apps, regular apps, and hidden apps that have windows, which might end up being essential for your ultimate goal.  But if you work most often with the more regular apps, then it's fairly clear which method is more suitable.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>The more generalised, potential problem—that doesn't really apply to your script as it stands, but is useful to know for future scripts if you attempt to use a similar technique—is the use of a variable as a means of referencing an `application` that has an undetermined name at compile time (before the script is run).</sub>

<sub>`bounds` is a fairly ubiquitous property of all scriptable applications's `windows`, which is why you (almost) get away this technique here.  However, if you picked a property or object class that *Script Editor* specifically does **not** contain, AppleScript won't recognise the terminology and assume it's simply a variable name.  In order for application-specific terminology to be recognised, a reference to that specific application needs to be made in some form, either by way of a `tell application "Finder" to...` or enclosing the relevant lines inside a `using terms from application "Finder"` block.</sub>

<sub>A good rule-of-thumb is that applications generally need to be known and specified at compile time in order to receive AppleScript commands.  There's no easy way to cater for varying options without using an `if...then...else if...` series of conditional blocks for each possible application.</sub>

<sub>This is a source of frustration particularly when it comes to applications that are seemingly similar in nature and, moreover, have a similar AppleScript dictionary, yet still don't share their terminology with one another for general use.  I'm thinking specifically of *Safari* and *Chrome*, both of which have objects referred to as `tabs`, making it easy to forget that a *Safari* `tab` is still a **different** class of object to a *Chrome* `tab`, and any attempt to write generalised code to script either or both will meet with failure.</sub>

Comment: I'm late to this party, but how would you use this method to tell windows where to go? Say you record every application's position and it can be read out the way you've done with references. Is there a simple way to record that information, then use it again to tell every window where to go with one line of code? Or do you have to use some kind of repeat loop?

Comment: @PatrickHennessey Sorry for the late reply.  If you want your windows to go to different locations, you would need a repeat loop as there’d be no way to turn a user-generated list of coordinates into something that would make syntactic or logical sense with the structure of a `whose` one-liner.  So the answer is no.  However, if you wanted to send all windows to the same single coordinate, that seems likely to work: `tell app id "sevs" to tell process "Safari" to set the position of every window to [0, 0]`.

Comment: After getting the array of window names and coordinates this generates, would it be possible to search the array for a name value and return the coordinates saved for that name previously?

Comment: @MaxWell Yes, it would.  But you can probably do one better, and construct an AppleScript filter to operate on all the windows of either one specific process, or all processes, and yield the bounds of the window that has a matching name.